# How can I use jQuery UI inside Confluence?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, confluence

I'm currently using jQuery inside a Confluence HTML macro to display a dialog.

```
<input type="text" id="shortName" style="height: 18px; width: 50px;">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="calendar">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#calendarDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: "600",
    width: "800",
    draggable: true,
    resizeable: true
  });
  jQuery("#submit").click(
    function() {
      var emp = jQuery("#shortName").val().replace('.', '');
      var url = <some-url>;
      var dialogTitle = emp + "'s day calendar";
      jQuery("#calendarDialog").dialog("open");
      jQuery("#calendarDialog").dialog( "option", "title", dialogTitle );
      jQuery("#calendarIFrame").attr("src", url);
      return false;
  });
    jQuery("#shortName").focus();
});
</script>
<div id="calendarDialog" style="overflow: none;"><iframe id="calendarIFrame" width="100%" height="99%" frameBorder="0" title="dialogBox"></iframe></div>
```

How can I also include stuff from jQuery UI inside Confluence? If I include jQuery UI in the code above (referencing http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js) it breaks the jQuery code in the macro.

Comment: Could you be more specific please. What statements don't work inside the `jquery(document).ready(function(){...})` structure?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, I refrained from posting the entire code because I think it's irrelevant in this case. Our Confluence comes with jQuery 1.6.x and may or may not ship jQuery UI too, I don't know. Including jQuery UI in my HTML macro seems to cause some collision with either Confluence stuff or the JS libs included with Confluence.

Comment: It's probably just use of English but your statement "If I include jQuery UI in the code above ..." is a little worrying. I just wanted to check you weren't doing something daft.

Comment: Code looks ok, there's nothing obviously wrong. You need to run some tests to see what's breaking. Start by commenting out the click handler to see if it can cope with the initial `jQuery("#calendarDialog").dialog({...});` statement on its own.

Answer (score 0):

In atlassian-plugin.xml:

```
<web-resource name="Resources" key="A-NAME-FOR-a-resource-key">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <resource type="download" name="jquery-ui.js" location="js/jquery-ui.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="jquery-ui.css" location="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
</web-resource>
```

In the file_name.vm:

```
$webResourceManager.requireResource("A-NAME-FOR-a-resource-key")
```

The file jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css should be stored under resources folder